# Is it ok to prime subfloor under engineered wood?

Tags: flooring

I'm going to be installing floating hardwood. Since I have the subfloors exposed (I screwed and caulked then because why not?) I thought I might also roll on mold-resistant primer like zinser. 
I don't have a mold issue but I figured why not? It doesn't take that long and if it abates mold if I ever have water intrusion then it's easy to do right now.

In it's final form the layers would be: finished wood, pad, barrier, paint, subfloor, spray foam (from below).

Comment: I see no problem.  Could help cover stale odors as well.

Comment: You ask "why not?" Twice. The answer in both cases is waste. Wasted expense, wasted materials, and wasted labor. If enough water gets under your floor to be a mold concern, your floor will be destroyed through warpage and staining anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I will normally seal underlayment in bathrooms and kitchens. This helps to for protect from moisture problems that are normal for these locations. I have not had any negative problems with sealing and in some cases I think it has helped with vinyl.